# How can I have access to Google Drive files with username and password from a java project which is using Google Client Library

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have to do a java project which update a file on google drive. I have followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java).

I want to have access with username / password and not with client ID and client Secret like I did in my test :

```
package test_api_google;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DriveCommandLine
{
    private static String CLIENT_ID = "*****************************";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "----------------------";

    private static String REDIRECT_URI = "oishdpi:g57s5g:464ty6";

    /* ________________________________________________ */
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
                Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).setAccessType("online")
                .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();

        String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();

        System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then type the authorization code:");
        System.out.println("  " + url);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String code = br.readLine();

        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);

        // Create a new authorized API client
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                credential).build();

        // Insert a file
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle("CHOUETTE");
        body.setDescription("A test document");
        body.setMimeType("plain/text");
        body.setEditable(true);

        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("src/data/document.txt");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());

        // Test lecture de fichiers
        File lectureFichier = new File();
        lectureFichier = service.files().get(file.getId()).execute();
        System.out.println(lectureFichier.getTitle());

        FileList listeFichiers = service.files().list().execute();
        int nbFichiers = listeFichiers.getItems().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < nbFichiers; i++)
        {
            File fichier = listeFichiers.getItems().get(i);
            if (fichier.getTitle().equals("My document"))
            {
                System.out.println("FICHIER TROUVE");
                break ;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm able to create a new file in my google drive account and to find it.
How can I do the same but with username / password.

There is a way to create client ID and client secret with connections informations?
I have to find how update a file too?

Comment: Apparently, i can't do this in java. But it's possible with android language. I will see this.

Comment: Google discontinued basic authorization for its APIs, you can't authenticate with username/password to talk to Drive backend.